# Selenium 2.39.0 and Firefox 28 - Fails to click radio buttons

Tags: jquery, firefox, selenium

I am running firefox 25 with version 2.34.0 of the Selenium server jar and my simple test to go to a page, fill in a couple of form values and click on a radio button runs fine.  The radio button is one of a JQuery Buttonset.

A colleague has FF 28 and version 2.39.0 of the Selenium jar.  Running exactly the same test, his fails as it doesn't click a radio button.  All the inputs that the test "hits" are identified by id so no XPath/CSS element ident or anything like that.

I allowed my FF to update to 28 and started using version 2.39.0 of the Selenium jar and I too now have the test failing to click the radio.  Updating to the latest selenium version (2.41.0) exhibits worse issues as it fails to click the first submit button detailed in the test script!

We have tried setting the font size for the windows environment to 100% but that has not solved the problem.  If I revert back to FF25 and Selenium 2.34.0, my test runs fine.

I cannot find anything useful on the selenium website related to this issue.  I know there was the issue of click events not firing if you had a Windows font size that was not set to 100%, but as I say, I have tried that solution to no avail.

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

### Update

So we didn't really find an answer to this but a workaround seems to be getting the selenium test to click on the label associated with the radio button you want to click in the buttonset.  In our case, we just made sure that each label had an id then changed the test script to click on the label rather than the radio.

Comment: whats the exact error it's spitting out?

Comment: I've had tests fail mysteriously because some combinations of Selenium + FF do not support native events and in turns out that my tests require native events support. Check whether native events support differs between your two combinations of Selenium + FF, just in case. This means checking whether the capability "nativeEvents" is true.

Comment: @sircapsalot - It is saying that the Element is not visible therefore it cannot interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Louis already suggested in the comment above and as can be seen from [Selenium changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG), version 2.39.0 only supports native events in FF 26 and to use FF 28, you need version 2.41.0 (which in turn doesn't support FF 26 anymore).

This is because Mozilla changed the way native events on Firefox work and thus you need to be very version conscious with FF 2X and Selenium.

Thus, you can ask your colleague to check what versions are compatible next time before giving you a lot of headache trying to use incompatible versions.